# The sum of the kernel density values is not 1?

Tags: matlab, references, density-function, kernel-smoothing

```
>> x = [randn(30,1); 5+randn(30,1)];
>> [f,xi] = ksdensity(x);
>> sum(f)

ans =

    5.5376
```

I ran the `ksdensity` function in MATLAB above. After getting the density values, I summed them up. I've got 5.5376, but I expected 1. What am I missing here? Is there any good introductory book that explains the mechanics of the kernel density estimation in line with the `ksdensity` function?

Comment: This question seems to come down to a misunderstanding of densities, which is addressed at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220.  Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you very much, whuber. Confusing, but I will dig in.

Comment: You appear to be summing the height of the density at some collection of values. Why would that sum to 1?

Answer (score 6):

it integrates to one, not sums to one.

`trapz(xi, f)` should return something close to 1.